# How do I use URL object with Fetch API in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, casting, fetch, webstorm

Fetch's first positional parameter `Input` type based on `lib.dom.d.ts` from latest WebStorm (181.4445.29) is `Request | string`.
Given this talk https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/256 about passing search query params to `fetch` call (using `new URL(...)`), how one should do it in TypeScript?

Without this assertion:

```
const response = await fetch(<string>url, fetchOptions);
```

I can't pass URL object to fetch method...

Or maybe it's WebStorm's problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't pass a `URL` object. Doing `<string>url` does not have any effect except to silence the compiler.

As the declaration of `fetch` says, it accepts either a string ('http://www.comtoso.com/') or a `Request` object. If you're building your URL with the `URL` object, you can get the URL in a string by using `toString`:

```
const response = await fetch(url.toString(), fetchOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks to JS engines invoking `.toSting()` on a primitive wraps it automagically with an object. That is how I upgraded myself to next level of TypeScript janitor.

Comment: [lib.dom.d.ts was updated](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-DOM-lib-generator/pull/1269) on 2022-03-02 to include `URL` in the `fetch()` typings. So presumably some near-future TypeScript release will eliminate the need for typing workarounds.

Comment: Thank you!  I burned a few hours on this problem.  Passing a URL object to fetch() didn't show any linting errors at code time but it errored out at compile time with "Argument of type 'URL' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestInfo'", but the MDN docs state that the first argument can be "A string or any other object with a stringifier — including a URL object — that provides the URL of the resource you want to fetch.", so I lost a few hairs from pulling.

Comment: @ChunkyChunk I'm still deep in this, does `fetch` actually accept a `URL` object as defined in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL or not? Because actually calling `fetch` with `URL` in my case returns an undefined body..

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos Fetch requires a string as the resource argument, but URL objects have a stringifier function (`url.toString()`), which can be used when working with URL objects:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch

Comment: @ChunkyChunk we realized that when the base url was missing a trailing slash we had this problem . . .